# Is there a SQL equivalent of pandas df.info()?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm just wondering if there is a short SQL query that works in the same way as pandas df.info() function does in Python? Something that quickly returns the table metadata.

Comment: In which database manager? Most of them have some sort of system tables where such information can be gathered, but their names and layouts are not standardised. Also, if your database interface implements DB-API (most do), the [.description](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description)  attribute on a cursor may be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The below should work:

```
select schema_name(tab.schema_id) as schema_name,
    tab.name as table_name, 
    col.column_id,
    col.name as column_name, 
    t.name as data_type,    
    col.max_length,
    col.precision
from sys.tables as tab
    inner join sys.columns as col
        on tab.object_id = col.object_id
    left join sys.types as t
    on col.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
order by schema_name,
    table_name, 
    column_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extract details form sql server then information_schema objects will help

```
select * from information_schema.tables t
join information_schema.columns c on t.table_name = c.table_name
where t.table_name = '<your table name>'
```